# Using "import" in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been using jspm and want to test out using Webpack.

I have followed [this](https://webpack.js.org/get-started/) tutorial.

However, when I run the example, the js errors on

```
 import _ from 'lodash';
```

Is there a different way I should be writing this import statement?  Should I use a transpiler on it to turn it into a require statement?

Comment: *"Should I use a transpiler on it to turn it into a require statement?"* If you are using webpack 1.x then yes.

Comment: Ah, yes, am using 1.14

Comment: You can also try webpack 2 which supports ES6 modules.

Comment: @FelixKling, if you want to post an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack 1 doesn't support ES6, so yes, in that case you have to use a transpiler.

Webpack 2 supports ES6 and can perform advanced optimizations when working with ES6 modules, but you might still need a transpiler if you use other ES6 features that are not supported by the environment you want to executed the code in.